# Change color of marks when plotting from csv

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a CSV file with data which I want to plot, I can do this by using:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=n, y=fn, col sep=comma, only marks] {dataratio.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This does the job but my dots are colored blue, how do I make them black? Just adding `color=black` doesn't do anything for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See, if

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[only marks, mark color=black] table [x=n, y=fn, col sep=comma] {dataratio.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives desired rezultat.

Comment: Works, thanks! :) I did color instead of mark color

Comment: That solutions works, but **not** because of `mark color=black`, which only changes the "other" color for the markers `halfcircle`, `halfcircle*`, `halfdiamond*` and `halfsquare*`. Please have a look at [my solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346939/95441)  to find out, why yours is working unintended.

Answer (score 6):

This is most probably, because you are adding the options in the wrong place. Correct would be to use all non-`table` options in the options of `\addplot`, i.e. move `only marks` from the `table` options to the `\addplot` options.

This will already give you the desired result, but have a look at the comments in the code why this is so and what would be the right way to change the color to something else than black for `\addplot` or something else than the default `cycle list` color for `\addplot+`.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
    % just some dummy data to show the differences between the two methods
    \begin{filecontents*}{dataratio.csv}
        n,fn,fo
        0,0,1
        1,1,2
    \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            % because now an option is given to `\addplot` (and not `\addplot+` the default
            % cycle list doesn't apply any more and the color black is used.
            \addplot [
                only marks,
            ] table [x=n,y=fn,col sep=comma] {dataratio.csv};
            % *with* the `+' the default cycle list still is used and then you can change
            % the marker color with `mark options'
            \addplot+ [
                only marks,
                mark options={
%                    % will set both, the `draw' and the `fill' color
%                    black,
                    % or you can set them separately to whatever you like
                    draw=red,
                    fill=green,
                },
            ] table [x=n,y=fo,col sep=comma] {dataratio.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]