# How to change style of graph from a csv (\addplot table)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I have seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188131/how-to-change-color-of-line-chart), but writing `\addplot+` did not fix the issue. I don't know how to (or if I can) apply [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346934/change-color-of-marks-when-plotting-from-csv) to my graph as the question is plotting only marks.

I have the following code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{abc.csv}
a, b
1,2
3,4
5,6
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[no markers,
table/col sep=comma,]
\addplot+ table[green, dashed, x=a,y=b,] {abc.csv}; 
\addplot [red, dashed] {x^2}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Whether I write `\addplot+` or just `\addplot`, the output is the same.

When compiled, the `x^2` graph comes out `red` and `dashed`, but the `abc` graph does not come with the options added. It remains solid blue.

[[image: Screenshot of Graph 1]

I got the warning `Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} into your preamble.`, but adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` to the preamble did not change the output.

How can I change the style of the plot with data from a `csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{abc.csv}
a,b
1,2
3,4
5,6
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
no markers,
table/col sep=comma,
]
\addplot[teal, dashed] table[x=a, y=b] {abc.csv}; 
\addplot[red, dashed] {x^2}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with dashed parabola and line]